# Adding built-in tools to python add-in toolbar

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

I want to make an ArcGIS Desktop add-in toolbar that has a regular ESRI built-in tool on it (like the buffer tool, or select tool, etc), instead of a custom tool. Is that possible or are we talking ArcObjects at that point?

This would be simple if I was looking to add tools for me only. But that's not the case. I'm looking to create a toolbar with standard tools that anyone in the organization could add to ArcMap via an add-in. We have a situation where sometimes the ArcMap profiles get reset in Citrix, and it would be nice when that happens, if the user could simply launch an add-in and get the standard tools back fairly easy. So using my above example, I want to make a toolbar with the buffer tool and the select tool, and we'll call it "Toolbar A". And anyone in the organization could load "Toolbar A" and get those tools. Is this possible using the ESRI python add-in solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch any tool using the pythonaddins module and the GPToolDialog. You will need to add a button on the toolbar and modify the click event. This should load existing or custom tools, but only if you have the appropriate license checked out.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python-addins/the-pythonaddins-module.htm

Comment: Perfect, this worked. Not sure why I couldn't find this before. Thanks for your help.